# How to set sum value on text feild when second value is set text?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

This is my demo cord.

```
<input type="text" id="my_input1" />
<input type="text" id="my_input2" />
<input type="text" id="total" />
<input type="button" value="Add Them Together" onclick="doMath();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function doMath()
{
    // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
    var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
    var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;

    // Add them together and display
    var sum = parseFloat(my_input1) + parseFloat(my_input2);
    document.getElementById('total').value=sum;
}
```

I want to work this function when my_input2 is enter it's value. Just like onclick method for button is there any event to set value to total tetxfeild after key release event?

Comment: You mean as the value is entered?

Comment: guess my_input1 = 250 and my_input2 = 500. After I enter 500 I want to set the sum to total..

Comment: Same as other answers you can try using different events like `onblur` -> which triggers after moving focus away from the text box,
try `onkeydown` also.

Comment: @Bharadwaj  both are not working :(

Comment: Is that `<script>` tag have an end tag (`</script>`) in your real code?

Comment: yep :D  let me edit my code in my real code.

Comment: Then add `alert()` after each line of the code, and check if every `alert()` hits. If any message is not alerted then the problem is with the previous line. If every `alert` hits then everything is working fine.

Comment: place entire `script` inside `<head></head>` tag.

Comment: live demo  http://jsfiddle.net/vivekh_RF/hFqeL/  check it here its working perfectly. Mark as answer if its worked or comment what error u have encountered

Comment: At the end its working.. :) thanks for your great support..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#my_input2").blur(function () {
            var sum = parseInt($("#my_input1").val()) + parseInt($("#my_input2").val());

            $("#total").val(sum);

        });


    });

</script>


<div>
    <input type="text" id="my_input1" />
    <input type="text" id="my_input2" />
    <input type="text" id="total" />
    <input type="button" value="Add Them Together" />

</div>
```

And also u should frame ur question correctly bcz u have added code in button click and asking us it should work after leaving textbox

Comment: shpuldn't I cover that $("#my_input2").blur(function () {
        var sum = parseInt($("#my_input1").val()) + parseInt($("#my_input2").val());

        $("#total").val(sum);

    });
with <script> </script>

Comment: i donno what u are doing there and whats the error but say 1 thing what did u used jquery or Javascript. if jquery please run and open press f12 after its loaded in web u can find error and tell us wht exactly what u getting

Comment: no mention happy coding. just ark the answer which helped u. so that it can distinguish it from other answers

Answer (score 0):

Put `onkeyup()` on second input field this will fire your function.

Something like that:

```
<input type="text" id="my_input2" onkeyup="doMath();" />
```

Comment: value is not setting in total after enter value to my_input2

Comment: You can even use  Jquery For that like blur event then once u left that textbox it automatically do what u says it to do

Comment: how can you explain @vivekh ?

Comment: $("#my_input2").blur(function () {        ur addition code   };

Comment: should I do any change in here. <input type="text" id="my_input2" />

Comment: Edited and also given answer check it and dont forgot to add js file and place ur jquery in head section and in script tag

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42745/discussion-between-vivekh-and-dilini)

Comment: Thanks for your all help. :) I got the answer finnaly.

Answer (score 0):

**try this** 

`<input type="text" id="my_input2" onchange="doMath();" />`

Comment: :( no not working.. is something wrong with my source code connection.

Comment: can you check this <input type="text" id="my_input2" onblur="doMath();" />

Comment: I did. Any more suggestions please.?

Comment: <input type="text" id="my_input2" onkeyup="doMath();" />

Comment: it should work have tried the one what i have said i mean using jquery